# How can I add a Hide ad button?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add a button so the user hide the add, I did this in swift but it seems quite different using objective-c this is the code I am using to display an add

```
#pragma mark iAd Deligate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I tried using

```
- (IBAction)hideAd:(id)sender {

        [ADBannerView.hidden = YES];
       }
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas? thanks!

Comment: You probably need the reference to the `ADBannerView` instance which is passed in the delegate methods and call `hidden` on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vadian but I don't understand how this is different from what I did?

Comment: You call the property on the class `ADBannerView` (+) but hidden is an instance property (-)  I guess

Comment: Not ADBannerView because it is a class. Use the reference instead .

Answer (score 0):

`ADBannerView` is the class. It doesn't have a hidden attribute for you to set to hide all ads. Instead, grab your banner and do this instead:

```
banner.hidden = YES;
```

That is, you need a reference to your banner, as opposed to it being passed in in the other two methods. You should keep a reference to the ad when you created it.

Comment: Works great , Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `hideAd:(id)sender` method.

```
- (IBAction)hideAd:(id)sender {
    [ADBannerView.hidden = YES];
}
```

`ADBannerView` is the class of your banner, not the banner itself.
The code below should work fine.

**Please note**: `_banner` should be replaced with the property name in which you declared your `ADBannerView`.

```
- (IBAction)hideAd:(id)sender {
    [_banner setHidden: YES];
}
```